Print invoice template based on item group
I use Microsoft Dynamics ax 2012 R2, when warehouse employee go to :
MyCompany/Accounts receivable/Common/Sales orders/All sales orders

Invoice Tab
Generate
Invoice ( then invoice the Sales order )

The system automatically print invoice and a copy based on a specific structure for the invoice page paper.
The issue is that on of the company suppliers needs to hide field ( expiry date ) and it's value from the invoice that printed .
In the Sametime, i need to have the same current structure for all the other companies.
So, i need to have two templates for the invoice and the template should depend on the item group when printing invoice.
I'm admin on the dynamics and can develop, but i don't know anything , i haven't write code or build or modify a report.
I need a clear steps to customize the invoice printing by make a new template that doesn't have this field.
additional Question : do i need to setup visual studio on the server or it can be efficient if i have it on my computer ?

I'm not sure this is the appropriate forum to teach you how to develop an AX report from scratch. I think you'll need to learn some, follow tutorials, etc. first. When you start developing reports and in AX, your best chance of success if having Visual Studio installed directly on the AOS and working there. When you become more advanced, you can try doing it with VS on your client, but even then, it can be finicky. Best to do directly on the AOS.

What @AlexKwitny said. Or, even better: hire a developer :)

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Why not make the "Expiry date" not visible depending a prior test?
Provided the invoice is based on SSRS, it should be relatively simply as SSRS have the option for a hiding a column:

That said SSRS reports are annoyingly difficult to get right, you may have to do some digging yourself. As an example, what would a truthful expression do? Show or hide? The correct answer is "hide", contradicting the header.
If the condition does not depend on values in the SalesInvoiceTmp table, you may need to add a field, and populate the value in the SalesInvoiceDP class.
Install the correct version of VS and the tools from AX install on the AOS server itself.
